# How to write wrapper function for git commands

Tags: linux, bash, git

I want to create a special alias for git log such that when I use that, it uses `--graph` and `--pretty` flags with a custom pretty format.

I know I can use the git alias but, I don't want to cuz I want to make it dynamic so that it can also be able to accept additional arguments/flags. Also, I want to learn how wrapping works in bash so I wanted to try it.

So here is what I want it to do;

when I use

```bash
git log spc
         ^_______(custom argument)
```

it runs following

```bash
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %C(grey)(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

so for this, I added this command ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731086/creating-an-alias-for-a-two-word-command-like-git-log)) in my `~/.bash_profile`

```bash
## git wrapper
git()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "log" ] && [ "$2" == "spc" ]; then
     shift
     set -x
     command git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative "$@"
  else
     command git log "$@"
  fi
}
```

but it's not working, here is the error that I got

```bash
+ git log spc
+ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' log == log ']'
+ '[' spc == spc ']'
+ shift
+ command git log --graph '--pretty=format:%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative spc
+ git log --graph '--pretty=format:%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative spc
fatal: ambiguous argument 'spc': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' aman ip-xx-x-xx-xx '~/one-xx-aws'
```

Comment: Instead of this, have you considered creating Git-level aliases such as `git logs`? Those are much easier to create than multi-word wrapper scripts.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't know much about bash scripting so don't know what do you mean by `shift 2`. And the error I am getting is `fatal: ambiguous argument 'spc':`

Comment: @user1686 I am aware of this but I am looking for multi-worded alias for some reason

Comment: @DarkstarDream Explaining the "some reason" in your question would be useful. Run `set -x` before running your command and show the output. If this doesn't show anything, add a line `set -x` before the `git log...` lines and re-run the function definition. In the `else` branch it should probably be `command git "$@"`

Comment: @bodo I have added the error output, can you check that

Comment: As you can see in the output `git log --graph ... --date=relative spc`, `shift` removes the first argument `log`, but not the second `spc`, so `"$@"` expands to `spc`. Try `shift 2` as already suggested by others.

Comment: git aliases can be a function definition followed by calling it: foo = 'f() { ... }; f'  This is a common mechanism, although getting the escaping correct can be tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's appending `spc` to the command: you can see that in the error output where on line 6 and 7 it writes `... --abbrev-commit --date=relative spc`.

I think it's because of the `"@"` part in your `if` block of your function. Perhaps you can skip the first argument (`spc`) and [only include the second argument onwards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82061/435767) by using `"${@:2}"` instead of `"@"`:

```
 command git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative "${@:2}"
```

Comment: Or simply use `shift 2` (or twice `shift`) as already suggested in comments.

Comment: Certainly! But comments [are not for answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment), so feel free to create an answer with your suggestion. That way others can give feedback on it (vote) and edit it to improve / update it.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR

Use `shift 2` instead of `shift` and remove the `log` in the `else` branch.

---

In your wrapper function

```
## git wrapper
git()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "log" ] && [ "$2" == "spc" ]; then
     shift    # **********************************************************
     set -x  
     command git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative "$@"
  else
     command git log "$@"
  fi
}
```

you use `shift` if the first two command line arguments match `log` and `spc`. This will remove the first argument `log`, but not the second `spc`. The `spc` will be appended to your command line as part of `"@"`. This results in the wrong command

```
git log --graph  ...  --date=relative spc
```

where `git` complains about the `spc` at the end.

As written in [Saaru Lindestøkke's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732657/992527), you could use `"${@:2}"` instead of `"@"` to remove one more argument from the list.

To me it does not make sense to use two different methods (`shift` and `"${@:2}"`) to remove the first and second arguments. I suggest to use `shift 2` (or twice `shift`) in combination with the original `command git ...` line.

Additionally, I assume that you don't want to insert an additional `log` argument when the command line arguments are not `log` and `spc`. That's why I removed the `log` in the `else` branch.

**Modified code:**

```
## git wrapper
git()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" == "log" ] && [ "$2" == "spc" ]; then
     shift 2
     command git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative "$@"
  else
     command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Note that `shift` works in every POSIX compatible shell. In `bash` you could alternatively use `"${@:3}"` and omit the `shift`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is way too complicated considering what it does. I would
think that a custom Bash function or a custom script would be a bit too
much for a use-case that exactly fits in a Git alias. But wrapping `git`
goes beyond that.

> I know I can use the git alias but, I don't want to cuz I want to make
> it dynamic so that it can also be able to accept additional
> arguments/flags.

Your wrapper passes on `"$@"`, which means that you can pass on
additional `git log` flags/switches. But git aliases allow you to do the
same thing.

```
git config --add --global alias.logcustom "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) ' --abbrev-commit --date=relative"
```

Now you can use it with other switches. Like limiting to five commits:

```
git logcustom -5
```

Or printing diffs as well:

```
git logcustom -p
```